# Which app is using location services?

Tags: windows-10, location-services

In *Location Privacy Settings*, under *Choose apps that can use your precise location*, I've disabled access to every app listed there.

[image: screenshot]

Despite this, every 30 minutes the location icon still appears in my tray, saying *Your location is currently in use*. It happens roughly every 30 minutes (but not exactly) around the 20 minute mark and 50 minute mark of every hour.

Is there a way to determine which app is responsible?

P.S. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1162732/what-app-used-my-location#comment1676344_1162732) says that only those apps listed under *Location Privacy Settings* can trigger that notification. I've turned off location for all those apps, but location is still being used. What gives?

Comment: Have you rebooted since changing those settings?

Comment: It's possible that I haven't rebooted since changing the settings

Comment: Try rebooting and see if it still has the problem.  It it entirely possible that the permissions are only enforced for *newly* running apps and that already running apps can retain permission if they already have access.

Comment: Only UWP applications are going to respect those permissions.  So what UWP applications did you have running when you notice the notification and are you sure the notification was recent?  If you don't clear out the notifications you can easily confuse yourself.

Comment: It just happened again, since rebooting. I haven't used any of the apps listed in the settings.

Comment: It's happening roughly every 30 minutes, around the 20 minute mark and 50 minute mark every hour.

Comment: I was wondering why this question went quiet and just now realized I have to tag you guys to notify you of my answers. oops. hi, @Mokubai

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: @DonielF Looks like the issue has resolved itself. I turned off _Location service_ a while ago, have applied updates since then. Turned it back on now and watched the tray - the reported behavior does not occur anymore